# How To Find A Closest Date To a Given Date?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two dataframes df1, df2. I need to construct an output that finds the nearest date to df1, whilst simultaneously matching the ID Value in both df1 and df2. df (Output Desired) shown below illustrates what I have tried explain above!

```
df1:

ID    Date
1     2020-01-01
2     2020-01-03


df2:
ID    Date 
11    2020-01-11
4     2020-02-03
5     2020-04-02
6     2020-01-05
1     2021-01-13
1     2021-03-03
1     2020-01-30
2     2020-03-31
2     2021-04-01
2     2021-02-02

df (Output desired)
ID     Date          Closest Date
1      2020-01-01    2020-01-30
2      2020-01-03    2020-03-31
```

Comment: Because the ID's match first then from 2021-01-13, 2021-03-03 and 2020-01-30. 2020-01-30 is closest to the original date 2020-01-01 seen in df1

Comment: how `2020-01-01` is closest to `2020-01-30`? Isn't `2021-01-13` is closest to `2020-01-01`?

Comment: Your question is unclear !!!!!  Explain the meaning of closest date more

Comment: @PrakashDahal I find it rather clear, "closest" meaning the date with the least days in between the source and target date, no?

Comment: Apologies, yes nearest/closest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to achieve it – assuming that the `Date` columns' `dtype` is [`datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html): First,

```py
df3 = df1[df1.ID.isin(df2.ID)]
```

will give you

```py
   ID       Date
0   1 2020-01-01
1   2 2020-01-03
```

Then

```py
df3['Closest_date'] = df3.apply(lambda row:min(df2[df2.ID.eq(row.ID)].Date, 
                                               key=lambda x:abs(x-row.Date)), 
                                axis=1)
```

- gets the `min` of `df2.Date`, where
- `df2[df2.ID.eq(row.ID)].Date` is getting the rows that have the matching `ID` and
- `key=lambda x:abs(x-row.Date)` is telling `min` to compare by distance,
- which has to be done on rows, so `axis=1`

**Output:**

```py
   ID       Date Closest_date
0   1 2020-01-01   2020-01-30
1   2 2020-01-03   2020-03-31
```

Comment: Thanks, love the detailed explanation too!